# Simple ui datepicker do not works

Tags: datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have problems with this datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>

<div id="checkinWrapper" class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" style="width:118px;" class="checkin search-option hasDatepicker" name="checkin" placeholder="Поаѓаме на">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div id="checkoutWrapper" class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker2" style="width:118px; margin-left:2px;" class="checkout search-option hasDatepicker" name="checkout" placeholder="Се враќаме">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

When I test it on a blank page it works okay but when I implement it in my current design it don't works (do not show). I don't know what causes that. Here are the scripts that I include:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe the problem occurs becouse I have other jQuery scripts implemented in my current design ? Any solution ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on the page?

Comment: Nope. It just don't work. The calendar is not showing when i click on the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the hasDatepicker class from both input tags it will work.

The datepicker plugin adds this class itself, as the class already exists no datepicker is created...

See http://jsfiddle.net/UYGXh/ for a working (non styled) example

Comment: I removed 'hasDatepicker' but still nothing happens. Maybe i should input other scripts ?

Comment: I got it. I had some .js files that use hasDatepicker and interfered with my datepicker.